Flutter: How to check the total of fields in a dynamic Form
I have multiple forms that are filled with dynamic fields consumed from a webservice.
class FirstSectionScreen extends StatelessWidget {
   FirstSectionScreen({super.key, required this.questions});

   final List<Question> questions;
   final GlobalKey<FormState> firstSectionFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Form(
         key: firstSectionFormKey,
         onChanged: () {
           print(totalAnsweredFields());
         },
         child: DynamicFields(questions: questions),
      );
   }

   String totalAnsweredFields() {
      Set<FormFieldState<Object?>> invalidFields = firstSectionFormKey.currentState!.validateGranularly();
      return '${questions.length - invalidFields.length} / $questions questions';
   }
}

What I need is to display a text like the following: "Questions answered X / Total questions Y"
I can know how many fields there are at the beginning, but it is not a constant total since each field can have dependent fields when activating or selecting one value or another. So the form can change the total number of fields while answering.
For the answered questions part I can do the subtraction of the total minus the invalid questions using the onChanged property of the Form:
Set<FormFieldState<Object?>> invalidFields = myFormKey.currentState.validateGranularly();
print(totalFields - invalidFields.length);

But first I need to know the total number of questions.
Is there any way to obtain the total number of questions present in the form?
